# Auto-arrange <li> elements into equal columns

Tags: django, django-templates

I have several values I'm rendering as `<li>` elements on my template and I want to further this by having them arranged into equal (or near-equal columns) automatically in the template.  How can I achieve this?

So far I'm rendering all the values as

```
<ul>
   {% for feature in features %}
      <li>{{ feature }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about styling each `li` with `style="float:left; width: {% width %}px;"`

All you have to do is calculate the width parameter... eg `width = 1000/features.length;`

Comment: @PHP_Jedi: I'll give this a show and see if it helps...I'll let you know
@Diodeus: I had initially wanted top-to-bottom, but left-to-right can still work fine

Answer (score 0):

In newer browsers you can achieve this behaviour using CSS:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 12px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 12px;
    column-count: 2; column-gap: 12px;
}
```

Unfortunately, IE doesn't play along (as of today). To work around this, I wanted to achieve the same effect using javascript. At first, I tried [Columnizer](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin), but that inserts `div`s into those innocent `ul` elements, which I didn't like.

So I went to build our own little plugin to do exactly what we need: [ColumnizeLists](https://github.com/teamaton/jquery-xt/tree/master/columnize-lists), part of our [jQuery extensions library](https://github.com/teamaton/jquery-xt).

Include the following script tag into your page:

```
<script src="https://github.com/teamaton/jquery-xt/blob/master/columnize-lists/tn.columnizelists.jquery.js"></script>
```

(or a local copy) and simply call

```
$('ul').columnizeLists({ useHeights: true })
```

and you're done :-)

Hope this helps.